# eclipse scala plugin console cannot display hebrew characters

Tags: eclipse, scala, encoding

I am trying to run the following scala code:
`println("world שלום")`.

but in eclipse, this is what I see in scala interpreter console:

> println("world שלום")
>
> world ????

Is it possible to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should tell where you see this. Is it the console? Also what platform are you running eclipse on.

You could try to add -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to your eclipse.ini file.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with Eclipse Indigo on Linux. It looks like you have some platform specific encoding issue ... but it's impossible to tell without more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Answer here

http://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/

relevant for all eclipse languages...

Taking the comment i got below into consideration, the short version of the link I gave says the following:

In eclipse, in the toolbar, in the 'run' button combo options, select 'run configurations'
There, go to the 'common tab' and change your encoding to UTF-8.